# Question on high school algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

I CANNOT PROCEED A SINGLE STEP IN QUESTION 9 AND QUESTION 10. Question is given in image.  please help.... Just the basic direction on how to proceed will help. 
Thank you for your consideration.

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvdYo.jpg)

Comment: Let $p=x^a$, etc.

Comment: For question $10$, given that $pqr=1$, answer $(a)$ is correct if and only if answer $(c)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9. If we *assume* that exactly one of the answer options is correct, just pick *one* specific set of values with $a+b+c=0$, e.g., $a=b=c=0$, and compute.
10. If we *assume* that exactly one of the answer options is correct, just pick *one* specific set of values with $pqr=1$, e.g., $p=q=r=1$, and compute. By the way, under the given condition, (a) and (c) are equivalent.

You might also notice that problem 9 is the same as problem 10 woth $p=x^a$, $q=x^b$, $r=x^c$. Hence you need only look out for answer options that match under these substitutions.